# What to keep in mind when playing at high frets?

Tags: electric-guitar, technique

When playing a melody or soloing around the top frets, 12-15, on electric guitar, is there anything specific to keep in mind? I'd guess the strings are more sensitive to accidental bending, and of course the fret spaces are smaller. Is there anything more I should be aware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The action is likely to be higher in this area of the fretboard, which may slightly affect your fretting action
- The tone of the notes for a given picking position will be mellower, because the lower harmonics will be excited relatively more
- the speaking lengths of the strings will be thicker relative to their length, so the harmonic structure will be less "ideal" (the sound will have component frequencies that are further away from being integer multiples of the fundamental).
- left hand muting is often easier, as the same light touch will damp the string faster

Comment: @Anna The sound will have component frequencies that are further away from being integer multiples of the fundamental. (Note that this isn't non-ideal in the sense of being 'bad', just in the sense of not adhering to the expected behaviour). This might make lower strings sound slightly more clangy and 'bell-like'.